# Replacement for Azure MobileService.Client.GetPush().RegisterAsync()

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services, mobileserviceclient

Since the Microsoft.Azure.MobileClient nuget currently is only supporting .net standard I am considering dropping it from my app-project. 
The only thing I am using it for is the RegisterAsync() call.

Can I do this in the backend (using the Azure Notification services) instead? I have my Firebase token and my apple token. I just need to register them in the Azure notification hub.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do this in the backend (using the Azure Notification services) instead?

If I understand you correctly, you could build the WebAPI backend for your mobile clients to register the notifications. And you could install the [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) NuGet package for processing the notifications. More details, you could refer to [Register for notifications by using the WebAPI back end](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification#register-for-notifications-by-using-the-webapi-back-end) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification#update-the-code-for-the-client-project) for communicating with your WebAPI for creating the registration.

Comment: Yes, well I use a version of this and they both do:
Hub = new SBNotificationHub(Constants.ConnectionString, Constants.NotificationHubPath);
Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) => {
             if (errorCallback != null)
                 Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
         });

and that call is what I am wondering if I could do on the server instead.